# jquery tooltip display from td contents

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip, html-table

I have a td which I do not want to have a title attribute. 
Within that td are some display stuff, and an input type="hidden"

I want to use jquery ui tooltip to display the value of the hidden input item

Everything is dynamic, so I was hoping to use the tooltip "open" method to override tooltip contents.

Any advice ?  I have not been able to get anything to work. The event will trigger, but I'm blowed if I can see how to update the tooltip content on the fly.

Comment: please create a jfiddle so we can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Um, with anything in it ?

Comment: yes put your html in the html section your javascript in the javascript section and your css (if any at all) in the css section..this way is easy to help you with your problem